# Laravel : optional parameters in url in every page?

Tags: laravel, routes

I need to have an optional parameter in every route in my app. (for example : sponsoring code)

Is there a way to check it on every page, without coding every possible route ?

In a classic website without framework we should make it like this :

if(isset($_GET['my_optional_parameter'])) { ... } (in a file included in every page)

Thanks in advance for your reply

Have a nice day

Frederic

Comment: I would add a custom middleware that checks this. Apply the middleware to your route group (create a group around the applicable routes if there isn't one already).
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/middleware#defining-middleware

Comment: yes for the middleware, but the question is : do i have to rewrite all routes with this optional parameter ?

Answer (score 0):

Just **basic** steps. Do **anything** you want! 
**1. Create middleware**

```
php artisan make:middleware SponsorMiddleware
```

**2. In app/Http/Middleware/SponsorMiddleware.php**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
    if ($request -> query('sponsor_id')) {
        //DO YOUR LOGIC HERE
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

**3. In app/Http/Kernel.php. Add to $middlewareGroups['web']**

```
\App\Http\Middleware\SponsorMiddleware::class
```

Comment: yes, i know for the middleware part, no problem for that ! My problem is about the routes, not about the middleware. Let's say i have a route which is "/my-page" if i go to "/my-page/mysponsorid" i have a 404. I should then add the route /my-page/{sponsorid?} to routes.php. Now let's say i have 1000 different routes, should i add 1000 new routes with {sponsorid?} or do i have an option to make it more easily ? thanks for your help !